# Oracle select similar values

Tags: sql, oracle, select, similarity

i have a database table with a lot of values like this: 340.13 and 232.89.

Now i want to select the value with the best match with a comparison value.

Is this possible without great effort?

Comment: show some table data and structre

Comment: What do you mean by **best match**. Can you explain on that. Sample data and expected output will clear out the doubts

Comment: Start [here](http://Sqlfiddle.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match values that are within +-10% of the search value and, if there are multiple values, will find the closest match by absolute difference.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11200/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME ( VALUE ) AS
SELECT 340.13 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 232.89 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 224.73 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100.00 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH search_values ( search_value ) AS (
  SELECT 330 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 230 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT search_value,
       value
FROM   (
  SELECT search_value,
         value,
         RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY Search_value 
                       ORDER BY ABS( value - search_value ) ) AS rnk
  FROM   table_name t
         INNER JOIN
         search_values v
         ON ( t.value BETWEEN search_value * 0.9 AND search_value * 1.1 )
)
WHERE  Rnk = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11200/1/0)**:

```
| SEARCH_VALUE |  VALUE |
|--------------|--------|
|          230 | 232.89 |
|          330 | 340.13 |
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty basic and common task so here is the general approach.

First you need to decide on "best-match-criteria". Basically it as a *function* of value stored in row and input value. So you can implement this function and evaluate it calling something like `MATCH_RATING(COLUMN, :value)` for each row. Now that you have this *rating* for every row, you can sort rows in any way you like and filter the most fitting one (`ROWNUM` is great for this as are analytic functions like `RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER`).

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT VALUE,
         MATCH_RATING(VALUE, :input_value)   RATING
  FROM   YOUR_TABLE
  ORDER BY RATING DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Then a good idea is to check whether your chosen criteria are implemented in language because if they are, using SQL features will surely be bettter performance-wise.

For example, if distance between two numbers is the only thing that concerns you, SQL will look something like this.

```
SELECT VALUE
FROM (
  SELECT VALUE,
         ABS(VALUE - :input_value)  DISTANCE
  FROM   YOUR_TABLE
  ORDER BY DISTANCE)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

If your *function* assumes 0 value on some interval meaning some rows should never get into your resultset then you should also use `WHERE` clause filtering useless rows (`WHERE MATCH_RATING(COLUMN, :value) > 0`).

Back to our distance example: let's accept distance not more than 5% of input value.

```
SELECT VALUE
FROM (
  SELECT VALUE,
         ABS(VALUE - :input_value)  DISTANCE
  FROM   YOUR_TABLE
  WHERE  VALUE BETWEEN 0.95 * :input_value AND 1.05 * :input_value
  ORDER BY DISTANCE)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

By the way, index on `YOUR_TABLE.VALUE` will surely be helpful for this example.

Comment: `match_rating()` is not an Oracle built-in function.  If you're suggesting that the OP build such a function - perhaps using `abs()` - then you should make that clear in your answer.

Comment: In my answer I probably mixed _function_ in general and _implementation_ a bit. Thanks, should be more clear now.